# Biztalk mapper altering nodes order

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I need to map document X to document Y, being both quite similar. X has the following [fragment of] XSD:

```
<xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="A" /> 
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="B" /> 
             <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="C" /> 
             <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="D"/> 
      </xsd:choice>
   </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Y has the same elements (A,B,C), but they're not within a sequence.

My problem arises when I test the map with the following input:

```
<doc-X>
    <A>...</A>
    <B>...</B>            
    <C>...</C>
    <D>...</D>            
    <C>...</C>
    <D>...</D>            
</doc-X>
```

I get something like this:

```
<doc-Y>
    <A>...</A>
    <B>...</B>            
    <C>...</C>
    <C>...</C>            
    <D>...</D>
    <D>...</D>            
</doc-Y>
```

I don't understand why is this happening, since I just map each element with its corresponding pair on the other schema.

**EDIT** : I've tried putting the property *PreserveSequenceOrder* to "Yes", but that hasn't worked

Comment: I can't test this right now but can you wrap the elements in a sequence.  So choice/sequence/elements

Answer (score 0):

XSD on its own does not guarantee that sibling elements will appear in any given order.   From what you've described, it sounds like the output is perfectly valid according to its schema.  Are you actually getting a failure in your test map?

Is there any way you can post the complete schema and document instances?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't post neither the XSD nor the XML :S . The generated output is valid according to its schema, as you mentioned, but the output is then fed into a couple of methods that would benefit from having said order.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that output because, Map always look for output document ( Document Y) Connections from top elment to bottom element. So in your case it will execute first elment A ( in Document Y) Links, afterthat B, after that C.

Try to modify the output doucment( Document Y) xsd to sth like this

```
    <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="D" /> 
                 <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="C" /> 
                 <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="B" /> 
                 <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="A"/> 
          </xsd:choice>
       </xsd:sequence>

</xsd:complexType>
```

You will see the difference.....